# What are the parameters of Meta Halachic principles?

Tags: halacha-theory, posek-psak-decisor-ruling, shalom-peace

In his book, **The Narrow Halakhic Bridge** Rabbi Ronen Neuwirth identifies a halachic category called meta-halacha (p. 249 and on) which he explains (I paraphrase) as principles a posek (decided of Jewish law) can apply that are outside of the standard halachic framework and allow for decisions to be rendered which may not comport with the strict letter of the law but rather the spirit or underlying principles of Judaism. He offers examples such as *mipnei darkei shalom*, in order to maintain the peace.
I would like to understand the parameters of this principle

1. What makes something a meta halachic principle? Are the criteria universally agreed upon?
2. Are these principles limited in any way?
3. Is there a list of these principles?
4. What happens if/when two meta halachic principles are in conflict?

Comment: Did he make up this category or is he citing it from elsewhere? If the former I don't understand your first question

Comment: It sounds like his personal term. You would probably have to ask him. Some rules such as mipnei darchei shalom are incorporated into standard halacha. Mipnei etc. has its own section of mishnayos in the fifth perek of gittin, iirc.

Comment: @N.T. "incorporated into the standard halacha" is no more objectively accurate than "principles a posek can apply that are outside of the standard halachic framework". It's all just a word game. I've even had people insist to me that "eit laasot lashem" is internal to standard halacha. If that's how you want to define "halacha" that's fine, but it's not an objectively "better" definition. I'd argue it's actually a less useful definition to use since you can't differentiate components as well, היינו דאמרי אינשי "if everyone is special then no one is."

Comment: @DoubleAA there is an entire book on the subject https://www.amazon.com/Meta-Halakhah-Logic-Intuition-Unfolding-Jewish/dp/1568219016

Comment: If the voters to close would explain I would be happy to try to improve the question which might be more helpful.

Comment: another person who discusses this concept https://www.chabad.org/multimedia/video_cdo/aid/3894343/jewish/Halachah-and-Meta-Halachic-Considerations.htm

Comment: One thing I would like to get to doing if I ever retire is translating the Shakh's pamphlet on the subject. It is printed in Yoreh Dei'ah right after siman 242. Would you be interested in my posting my own metatheory?

Comment: As for agreement on the rules... No. For example, the Arukh haShulchan's methodology relies heavily on how to understand the gemara, in light of rishonim and earlier acharonim as well as accepted practice (that their rabbis apparently accepted). The Mishnah Berurah doesn't have the same confidence that we can pasqen based on understanding the law, and instead is more likely to imply the rules of doubt (safeiq). Rather than primary sources or looking to understand what practice implies "we hold", he focuses on later posqim.

Comment: My metatheory is my understanding of the various axes posqim look to. With no absolute statement about prioritizing them.

Comment: @N.T. re asking him, he passed away young unfortunately